# How to dynamically render a stateful component in React

Tags: reactjs

How does one go about dynamically rendering a stateful component that takes in props that can change after render? I have tried storing components in state and then mapping out the state however the components do not update when the props passed into them has changed.
Example:

```
export default App(props){
const [name, setName] = useState(null)
const [articles, setArticles] = useState([])

return (
      {articles.map((article) => {article})}
      <input type="text" value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}/>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setArticles([...articles, <Article name={name}/>])}}>Add Article</button>
)

}
export default Article(props){
    return (
       <p>props.name</p>
)

}
```

In my example, when I update the name state by changing the input field, none of the rendered articles update to reflect this change, only new additions when the add article button is pressed after the name has been changed, I want them to update as the state changes, how do I do this?

Comment: You are basically asking, "How does React work?"  Please add code to illustrate your specific problem.

Comment: Added an example

Comment: You want all articles to display the new name?

Comment: Yes correct, this example is a much simpler version of what I am trying to achieve but it is the same principle

Answer (score 1):

This is a clean-up of your code that basically produces a "To Do" list.  Some mistakes you had...

1. Multiple `default` exports
2. Unnecessary use of `map`
3. Lack of curly braces around `props.name`

```
export default function App(props){
  const [name, setName] = useState(null)
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([])
  
  return (
<>
  {articles}
  <input type="text" value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}/>
  <button type="button" onClick={() => setArticles(
    [...articles, <Article name={name}/>]
  )}>Add Article</button>
</>
)
  
  }

export function Article(props){  
  return (
    <p>{props.name}</p>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I think you have missed my question, I need the articles to update whenever the name state changes.